# How do I run a binary program without showing the gear icon?

Tags: applescript, automator, android

I created a automator workflow, add a `Run Shell Script` part and put these lines in:

> /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd

I saved it as an app and it works.

But I will always see a gear icon on the menu bar.

I tried to put a `&` or `nohup`, if so the program won't start.

Any ideas? The `android` I'm trying to execute is a shell script

Answer (score 1):

You will always see the gear in the menu bar if you are using Automator. If you want it to exit quickly, create a wrapper that forks off your `android` script into another process, and exits.

For example, you could run

> echo "/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd" | /usr/bin/at now

*(source for script is from this [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6474971) page near the bottom)*

Comment: Can you explain how to implement this? Ideally with an example?

Comment: @guptron enjoy.